# tinyMCE default content called from database

Tags: tinymce

I used tinyMCE for the content of a blog posting. My problem is regarding on the editing of the blog. So when the author edits on his/her blog, the content must load in the tinyMCE editor called from the database like:

```
query = select id,title,content from blogs where id='id'

-input id="subject" value="echo title" -

-textarea- id="content"- "echo content" -textarea-
```

But this obviously does not work. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Thariama i'm a newbie on using tinyMCE so i just tried a code like <textarea id="content"><?php echo $content; ?><textarea> what are ways to set a default content of the textarea which is linked to tinyMCE except for using .setDefault("default content here") because the content will vary depending on what content to be loaded from the database.

Comment: so, your editor initializes, but does not hold the right content? can you verify that $content - holds the correct content?

Comment: @Thariama yes.. i tried to echo the $content in other elements such as input text and it contains the correct content only that it does not load in the text area which the tinyMCE is connected to..

Comment: Gosh i'm such an idiot. I already solved it. Just a misplaced close bracket :(